# How can I get a VSCode Extension to show the install tutorial?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently installed the Python VSCode extension, and when I did it popped up with a handy tutorial page.

However, after closing it, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this page back.

I've tried reinstalling the extension, checking through all of the commands, modifying settings, nothing seems to work.

Checking through [the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/package.json) for the python extension, there seems to be a `onWalkthrough:pythonWelcome` that creates this page. However, I have absolutely no idea how to manually invoke this again.

Does anyone know how to do this? I know it's not strictly necessary, but I just assumed it would be easy and was surprised and stubbourn when it wasn't.

Comment: Suggest ask this question directly to devs on [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions)

Comment: Done that ty, hopefully they know!

Answer (score 1):

After [asking the devs directly](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions/17801#discussioncomment-1510088), it seems that it's extremely simple!

`Get Started: Open Walkthrough...` in the command palette will open a menu of available walkthroughs from extensions you've installed, including the Python one I was trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

It has been removed, you can refer to these page for more details:

[Should we not open the start page if a user already has a folder open?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1005)

[Python Start Page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-june-2020-release/)

[Welcome page opens while I am starting to type in a python file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14508)

[Remove start page and its build dependencies](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/16834)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the start page I'm looking for, it's the welcome page. And the welcome page is definitely still in, because I saw it last night when installing python for the first time.

Comment: Looks like the `start page` was the `welcome page`, and it only display when the first time you installed the python extension. It used to display with the command of `Open start page` and when the python extension update, but both of them have been removed. If you are not sure, could you have a look at this picture [page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-june-2020-release/)? this is the picture in the second link in the answer.

Comment: Had an answer from the devs, have added it below